# Identify user group on item creation

Tags: list, permissions, ad, custom-permission-level

I'm in the process of creating a custom list. All Items in this list will be added by two departments. what I'm looking to do is record which department the user belongs to.

Example: User 1 is in permission group Department 1, User 2 in in permission group Department 2.

User 1 creates a new item in the list. Column in list shows this was added by a user in Department 1.

Essentially I'm looking for a way to record this without including any choice columns for department and was hoping there's a way I can achieve this via the AD or Permission Groups as we will need to know which records have been added by which department in our reporting.

Any suggestions/ideas of best way to achieve this or the closest I can get to this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have the department recorded in the AD then you can achieve this via workflow in SP Designer.

1. Add the column that you will store the Department in
2. In list workflow add  "Set Department to ..."
3. Set Lookup for String to

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is a great answer. We don't currently have Department recorded in AD. We do but this is managed by our HR department who haven't kept this up to date and will not provide the correct information in most cases. I have however come up with a work around by creating another list containing both users and departments and a workflow that will update the department column with this information based on created by.

Comment: Shame on your HR department. If only they realised that their processes are causing pain elsewhere. Glad you found a solution - shame it has to be another managed list - but that is not your bad!